# Android 4.0 vs 4.2 API differences

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to program for Android 4.2 device but the book I have is teaches Android 4.0 called [Beginning Android App Development 4](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Android-4-Application-Development.productCd-1118199545.html). So, I am having problems running the first program targeted for Android 4.2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text'
>   with value
>   '@string/hello'). activity_main.xml   /HelloWorld/res/layout  line
>   7 Android AAPT Problem
>
> [I18N] Hardcoded string "And this is a clickable button!", should use
>   @string resource  activity_main.xml   /HelloWorld/res/layout  line
>   20    Android Lint Problem
>
> [I18N] Hardcoded string "This is my first Android Application!",
>   should use @string
>   resource  activity_main.xml   /HelloWorld/res/layout  line 15 Android Lint
>   Problem

I would like to where can I find the difference between 4.0 APIs from 4.2? Should I continue reading the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that first error is simply because you haven't created a resource in your `strings.xml` called `hello`. The other two warnings are just because Android Lint wants you to use a string resource (like the first one), instead of hardcoding the strings.

Neither of these have anything to do with any differences between Android 4.0 and 4.2 however.

If you are still curious about the differences in these API levels, the Android documentation has plenty of information.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes.html
https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/22/changes.html

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the book assumes that you're a pro rather than a beginner. It's filled with a lot of code with almost zero explanations. Any suggestions for changing the book?

Comment: I personally haven't read any books on Android, so I can't help you there. The way I started learning was through the provided tutorials and documentation, because they are actually pretty thorough. https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 1):

your problem ist not really a problem with API´S its just because you used a string that is not in strings.xml file(hardcode string). you can ignore it (should be just an advisement not a error) or just create a the string (only if you go to use that string more than once.